# Upload images associated to a meteor collection

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm having a hard time understanding the whole process of uploading images to a certain Meteor collection eg.(the belongs_to and has_one association with rails).

I have a portfolioitem collection, this is the file:

```
PortfolioItems = new Mongo.Collection('portfolioItems');

ownsDocument = function(userId, doc) {
  return doc && doc.userId === userId;
}

PortfolioItems.allow({
  update: function(userId, portfolioItem) { return ownsDocument(userId, portfolioItem); },
  remove: function(userId, portfolioItem) { return ownsDocument(userId, portfolioItem); },
});

Meteor.methods({
    portfolioItemInsert: function(portfolioItemAttributes) {
        check(Meteor.userId(), String);
        check(portfolioItemAttributes, {
            title: String
        });

        var portfolioItemWithSameTitle = PortfolioItems.findOne({ title: portfolioItemAttributes.title});
        if (portfolioItemWithSameTitle) {
            return {
                portfolioItemExists: true,
                _id: portfolioItemWithSameTitle._id
            }
        }

        var user = Meteor.user();
        var portfolioItem = _.extend(portfolioItemAttributes, {
            userId: user._id,
            submitted: new Date()
        });

        var portfolioItemId = PortfolioItems.insert(portfolioItem);
        return {
            _id: portfolioItemId
        };
    }
});
```

This is the submit.js template for submitting portfolio items:

```
Template.submit.events({
    'submit #submit-form': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var portfolioItem = {
            title: $(e.target).find('#submit-title').val()
        };

        Meteor.call('portfolioItemInsert', portfolioItem, function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                return alert(error.reason);
            }

            if(result.portfolioItemExists) {
                alert('Title already taken!');
                pause();
            }

            Router.go('portfolioItemPage', {_id: result._id});
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you give a try to `FSCollection`? if not i think its a good option to accomplish this.

You can just declare the collection.

I Suggest you to use `GridFS`.

just run this 2 commands

```
meteor add cfs:standard-packages
meteor add cfs:gridfs
```

Declare the collections like any others.

```
Images = new FS.Collection("Images", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.GridFS("Images")]
});
```

And you can associate the Simple collection with the FSCollection using metadata.

```
Template.exampe.events({
  'click #addImage':function(){
    var file = $('#inputPng').get(0).files[0],
                fsFile = new FS.File(file);
                fsFile.metadata = {
                    ownerId:Meteor.userId(),
                    title:$(e.target).find('#submit-title').val()
                }
                Images.insert(fsFile,function(err,result){
                    if(!err){  
                       console.log(result)                  
          }
       })
    }
 })
```

At this moment the [README](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS) on the fsCollection its empty so I made a little [DEMO](http://demo.fscollection.meteor.com) about this.

Comment: Ok the collection part makes sense, thanks for that. I'm still confused with the metadata part. For example I would create an html file upload button and create a click event for the input. In my case would I just do fsFile.metadata= { portfolioItemId: result._id }??

Comment: if in this case result will be the callback from the `Meteor call ('portfolioItemInsert')` i think yes i never do that, but also why don't forget about the `PortafolioItemns Collection` and just create 1 `FSCollection `holding the `userId,submitted` fields as Metadata? i think it will be a better option split 2 Collections into just 1an FSCollection its like any other Collection, so the `allows/deny inserts remove etc` it will be exactly the same, just withe plus that we hold `files` with `metadatas`

Comment: Is there any way to see an example of what you mean? I've obviously been following the discover meteor lesson. It would be great to see other options of how things can be done.

Comment: Yep i put a demo on the answer i try to show how it works, also on my github i have the code if you want to look it

Comment: Did you get it @dileet?

Comment: Yup I'm starting to get it. Maybe you can help me with this then. What if I only want to show an image based on the ID in the url?

Comment: On the url of the file? I never try that since http.ulr method returns a long url string but i think you can