# How to Store Files into MeteorApp?

Tags: meteor

Is There a way to store file in Meteor Apps? if yes how?

Also how can i store file data in user defined collections using meteor?

I didn't get any idea about this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to store files into MeteorJs is using the [FSCollection Package](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS).

This question already have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661985/upload-images-associated-to-a-meteor-collection/28662143#28662143)

I Made a little [Demo](http://demo.fscollection.meteor.com) and here is the [Source Code](https://github.com/Ethaan/simple-uploadFS)

In Resume just run this 2 commands

```
meteor add cfs:standard-packages
meteor add cfs:gridfs
```

Declare a simple `FScollection`

```
Images = new FS.Collection("Images", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.GridFS("Images")]
});
```

and do this simple **Event Handler**.

```
Template.exampe.events({
  'click #addImage':function(){
    var file = $('#inputPng').get(0).files[0],
                fsFile = new FS.File(file);
    //and also store file data in user defined collections using meteor
                fsFile.metadata = {
                    ownerId:Meteor.userId(),
                    title:$(e.target).find('#submit-title').val()
                }
                Images.insert(fsFile,function(err,result){
                    if(!err){  
                       console.log(result)                  
          }
       })
    }
 })
```